# php foreach array issue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, linkedin-api

I've got an array which outputs:

```
stdClass Object ( [firstName] => Rupert [headline] => Managing Director at 
READ Advisors [lastName] => Bowen-Jones [pictureUrl] => 
https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_yrLwHnXDTWGSypSo-
B_NHz9hiu52pMpoOAAqHzLxpolpijIEr9zbQvllDTL1xYj6g1FvFtBsywhL )
```

And I'm trying to pick out each item:

```
foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
echo "<br />" . $value['firstName'] . "<br />";
}
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
stdClass Object ( [firstName] => Rupert [headline] => Managing Director at 
READ Advisors [lastName] => Bowen-Jones [pictureUrl] => 
https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_yrLwHnXDTWGSypSo-
B_NHz9hiu52pMpoOAAqHzLxpolpijIEr9zbQvllDTL1xYj6g1FvFtBsywhL ) 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstName' in 
/home/readadvisors/readadvisors.com/auth/linkedin/callback.php on line 26

R

Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstName' in
/home/readadvisors/readadvisors.com/auth/linkedin/callback.php on line 26
M

Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstName' in 
/home/readadvisors/readadvisors.com/auth/linkedin/callback.php on line 26

B

Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstName' in
/home/readadvisors/readadvisors.com/auth/linkedin/callback.php on line 26
h
```

Your help would be much appreciated!!
Rupert

Comment: it's not a array it is a object so you need to use like $obj->firstName

Comment: use `$user_data->firstName`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $user_data is an array of objects

```
foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
echo "<br />" . $value->firstName . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work... but this does: echo $user_data->firstName;